# Does CPU know whether it is reading from RAM or some peripheral?

Tags: cpu, ram, pci

As far as I know, if CPU wants to read some data, say 1 byte, either from RAM or some peripheral like a hard drive, it'll write the address onto its address buses and output **read** signal via its control bus (assuming that a cache missing occurs), and then wait for the data to come via the data bus. It's Northbridge that needs to tell that the address it's received from CPU represents a location in RAM or a peripheral so as to forward the **read** request to the proper bus --- RAM controller or PCI bus. CPU itself doesn't know about this, though it might feel that it has to wait a longer time for the data to come from some addresses than from other addresses.

Am I right?

Comment: This isn't directly related to software development. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) looks like a better venue.

Comment: Are you essentially asking how can the compiler determine how many `nop`s are required after a load operation, if the target address is only known at runtime?

Comment: @barak manos: I mean, from CPU's point of view, are all the devices it communicates with the same except for their addresses?

Comment: The CPU doesn't know any devices. All it knows are buses, just like you said.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU only uses addresses...the addresses themselves decide whether it is an IO address or memory address based on some bits in the address.